# Mocking requests/responses, mock object has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm new to the mocking library and so far it's been giving me trouble. I'm trying to test a Url parsing method that takes a response from an `initialUrl` which is then parsed in the method. I set `autospec=true` so I think it should have access to all methods in the requests library (including `response.url`) I'm trying to mock both `get` and `response` though I'm not sure if that's needed?

My getUrl method that takes a response and returns its parsed contents:

```
def getUrl(response):
    if response.history:
        destination = urllib.parse.urlsplit(response.url)

        baseUrlTuple = destination._replace(path="", query="")
        return urllib.parse.urldefrag(urllib.parse.urlunsplit(baseUrlTuple)).url

    raise RuntimeError("No redirect")
```

Test method:

```
def testGetUrl(self):
    initialUrl = 'http://www.initial-url.com'
    expectedUrl = 'http://www.some-new-url.com'

    mock_response = Mock(spec=requests, autospec=True)
    mock_response.status_code = 200
    mock_get = Mock(return_value=mock_response)
    #mock_get.return_value.history = True
    resp = mock_get(self.initialUrl)
    mock_response.history = True
    resultUrl = getBaseUrl(resp)
    self.assertEqual(resultUrl, expectedUrl)
```

When I run the test, I get

```
    raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'url'
```

Comment: You access the `.url` member of response at `destination = urllib.parse.urlsplit(response.url)`. Just mock it too

Comment: Would I be mocking the `urllib` class? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would fix the code in your question so that it actually runs.

You have several options, the easiest being just adding `url` to the list of attributes you're mocking:

```
mock_response.url = <your URL>
```

But it's also important to understand that you're trying to use the requests library as a specification for the mock, when you should be using `requests.Response()` if you want the url attribute to be automatically generated.  You still have to assign whatever url you want to use to it though, or you'll be comparing a Mock object to an int in your function.

Take a look at the documentation involving spec if you want to learn more:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html